# How can i exclude some element from my array? (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, basically i use an HTML select filled with the arrays of registered users

```
<label >
  <b>
    <i style="opacity:0.8">Users:</i>
  </b>
</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select
  class="form-control w-50 mb-5"
  style="display:inline;"
  v-model="filter"
  @change="userfilter"
>
  <option id="userbox" v-for="user in userlist" :key="user.userlist">{{user}}</option>
  <option>All</option>
</select>
```

than with `v-model="filter"` i set the filter value that initially is empty

```
export default {
name: "completed",
data() {
return {
  filter: "",
  userlist: "",
  archive: [],
  supportarchive: [],
  selecteduser: ""
};
},
```

I have also created a suppor-tarray `supportarchive:[]` which function is to fill the original array when this condition result true:

```
methods: {
userfilter: function() {
  this.selecteduser = this.filter;
  if (this.filter == "All") {
    this.supportarchive=[];
    this.archive = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("completedtasks"));
  } else {
    this.supportarchive = this.archive;
    this.archive = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.supportarchive.length; i++) {
      if (this.supportarchive.taskuserID == this.selecteduser) {           
        this.archive.push(this.supportarchive[i]);
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Ok so if the `filter` is all then i fill my array from the `localStorage` but if the `filter` has another value then i do a backup of my original array `archive` in `supportarchive`, then i empty the original one and if the condition is meeted i push the element of my `supportarchive` into my original one `archive` but it doesn't work and i don't know why

Answer (score 1):

Is `this.supportarchive` an object and not an array? Then it has no length property and won't work in the loop.

One solution is to get the object keys and loop based on those;

```
var keys = Object.keys(this.supportarchive)
var tempArr = []
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

  let item = this.supportarchive[keys[i]];

  if (item.taskuserID == this.selecteduser) {
    // You should put this into a new temporary array.
    // Dont change the array you are looping
    // this.archive.push(this.supportarchive[i]);

    tempArr = item
  }
}

// Parse back into json
this.archive = JSON.parse(tempArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code  do something like `this.supportarchive[i].taskuserID`

```
methods: {
userfilter: function() {
  this.selecteduser = this.filter;
  if (this.filter == "All") {
    this.supportarchive=[];
    this.archive = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("completedtasks"));
  } else {
    this.supportarchive = this.archive;
    this.archive = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.supportarchive.length; i++) {
      if (this.supportarchive[i].taskuserID == this.selecteduser) {           
        this.archive.push(this.supportarchive[i]);
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

**Recommended method** use filter on array

```
this.archive = this.supportarchive.filter(u => u.taskuserID === this.selecteduser);
```